# How to use the function "table:get" (table extension) when 2 keys are required?

Tags: hashtable, netlogo

I have a file .txt with 3 columns: ID-polygon-1, ID-polygon-2 and distance.
When I import my file into Netlogo, I obtain 3 lists `[[list1][list2][list3]]` which corresponds with the 3 columns.

I used `table:from-list list` to create a table with the content of 3 lists.
I obtain `{{table: [[1 1] [67 518] [815 127]]}}` (The table displays the first two lines of my dataset).

For example, I would like to get the value of distance (list3) between ID-polygon-1 = 1 (list1) and ID-polygon-2 = 67 (list1), that is, 815.

How can I use `table:get table key` when I have need of 2 keys (ID-polygon-1 and ID-polygon-2) ?

Thanks very much your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`table:from-list`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arraystables.html#table:from-list) will not help you there: it expects "a list of two element lists, or pairs" where the "the first element in the pair is the key and the second element is the value." That's not what you have in your original list.

Furthermore, NetLogo tables (and [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) in general) cannot have two keys. They are always just key-value pairs. Nothing prevents the value from being another table, however, and in your case, that is what you need: a table of tables!

There is no primitive to build that directly, however. You will need to build it yourself:

```
extensions [ table ]
globals [ t ]

to setup
  let lists [
    [   1   1 ] ; ID-polygon-1 column
    [  67 518 ] ; ID-polygon-2 column
    [ 815 127 ] ; distance column
  ]
  set t table:make
  foreach n-values length first lists [ ? ] [
    let id1  item ? (item 0 lists)
    let id2  item ? (item 1 lists)
    let dist item ? (item 2 lists)
    if not table:has-key? t id1 [
      table:put t id1 table:make
    ]
    table:put (table:get t id1) id2 dist
  ]
end
```

Here is what you get when you print the resulting table:

```
{{table: [[1 {{table: [[67 815] [518 127]]}}]]}}
```

And here is a small reporter to make it convenient to get a distance from the table:

```
to-report get-dist [ id1 id2 ]
  report table:get (table:get t id1) id2
end
```

Using `get-dist 1 67` will give the `815` result you were looking for.

Comment: I don't understand why the code doesn't work after importing my landscape into Netlogo from `import-world`. However, it works when I don't import my landscape. Is it possible that the Table extension doesn't work with `export-world`? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Looks like you've stumbled over an old bug: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/12

Comment: I think you'll need to re-initialize your table from the original lists after doing `import-world`. Can you do that?

Comment: Thank you Nicolas ! How can I re-initialize my table ? In my function, I import, in a first time, my dataset as this :`let data split-into-n-lists 3 read-file-into-list "Polygons.txt"`. Then, I used the same code from `set t table:make....`. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Just do the same thing again after you've called `import-world`.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I called my function before and after I've called import-world but the code doesn't work. My program crashes. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: "the code doesn't work. My program crashes" is not enough information to help you. Maybe it would be worth opening a new question where you could give more details? (the code where you import, what message you get when it crashes, etc.)