# Netlogo:: Bloodthirsty Cannibalistic Turtles & Myself/Self Confusion

Tags: hashtable, netlogo

New NetLogo User and first-time poster here, with some cannibalistic turtles on my hands.

About my model:

My turtles have a bodysize (bsize), and a breed (male, female, juvenile turtles). They move around in a random fashion and encounter each other on patches. When two turtles land on the same patch, my little beasts size each other up, and depending on a probability of cannibalism (PrCan) specific to the larger turtle's breed and the body size ratio (bsize_ratio) between the two, the bigger one eats the smaller one.

I don't think this is relevant, but I have created a table (PrCanTable) of 3 lists with two keys (body size ratio, breed, and probability of cannibalism) using table:make from instructions I found [on this stack overflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186352/how-to-use-the-function-tableget-table-extension-when-2-keys-are-required)

To continue, the bigger turtle looks up the probability of cannibalizing (PrCanT) in the table (PrCanTable), then picks a random number (random-float) and compares it to the probability (PrCanT). If the random number is less than or equal to the probability, the little turtle dies. So sad!

Unfortunately, my bloodthirsty turtles are misbehaving. I am running into a problem:

**There is no agent for MYSELF to refer to.
error while fa 25 running MYSELF
  called by procedure CANNIBALIZE
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'**

NetLogo has helpfully highlighted the last instance of myself in my code...but I don't know why. I think this is a problem with my own understanding of myself vs. self. I have read as much as I can, but honestly am still stumped. Can anyone take a look at this code and let me know?

```
to-report get-PrCan_T [ bsize_ratio_T breed_T ]
report table:get (table:get PrCanTable bsize_ratio_T) breed_T
end

to cannibalize
if ( any? turtles-here with [bsize > [bsize] of myself])
and ( random-float 1 <= get-PrCan_T ( precision( bsize / bsize of myself ) 1 ) ( [breed] of self ) )
[die]
end
```

Comment: (( Would this be better with a fully reproducible example? ))

Comment: You get +1 from the title alone. (And yes, reproducible examples are always better.)

Comment: The code you posted here cannot compile, by the way: you're missing brackets around `bsize` in `bsize of myself`.

Comment: Another quick note: `[breed] of self`, is redundant. You can access `breed` (or any other turtle variable) directly for the current turtle: `of self` is never needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, `self` and `myself` are confusing at first, but once you get the hang of it, it's really not that hard. What you need to understand is that every piece of NetLogo code runs into a "context". That context, by default, is the observer, but some primitives can introduce a new context.

`ask` is the most obvious way to introduce a new context: the command block that you pass to `ask` (delimited by `[` and `]`) puts NetLogo in the context of a turtle. Inside that context, `self` refers to the current turtle.

But sometimes you introduce a new turtle context *inside an existing turtle context*! Inside that new context, `self` changes meaning: it now refers to the turtle from the inner context. But what if you still want to refer to the turtle from the outer context? That's what `myself` is for.

Assuming that `cannibalize` is a procedure that is run by a turtle, your use of `myself` in `turtles-here with [bsize > [bsize] of myself]` is correct: the turtle running the `with` block is `self` (which you don't need to specify) and turtle running `cannibalize` (the "outer" turtle) is `myself`. The inner context was introduced by `with`.

But in the second part of your `if` condition (everything that follow `and`) there is no inner context anymore: you're not inside the `with` block anymore. So `myself` is not defined anymore. There is only `self`.

Your code is also made harder to debug by the fact that you're trying to pack everything in the same long `if` condition. Try splitting it up by using multiple local variables:

```
to cannibalize
  let bigger-turtles-here turtles-here with [ bsize > [ bsize ] of myself ]  
  if any? bigger-turtles-here [
    let cannibal one-of bigger-turtles-here
    let ratio precision ([ bsize ] of cannibal / bsize) 1
    let p get-PrCan_T ratio breed
    if random-float 1 <= p [ die ]
  ]
end
```

One final note: in both your version and mine, the turtle running the `cannibalize` procedure is the one that gets eaten! That's confusing. I would either rename the procedure to `get-cannibalized` or switch things around so that the turtle running the procedure is the one that does the eating. (Naming is important!)

Comment: Thank you, @Nicholas! This code worked great, and splitting into local variables made both this function and others a LOT easier to read/de-bug.